# Writing a PHP code with session variables in PHP

Tags: php, session, fwrite

I cant able to write the session into a .php file

I can successfully echo out the session variable in this file, but cant save the output of that variable in the file i created "m3.php". Its displaying the php code only.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION["sub"];
    $filename = "m3.php";
    $ourFileName =$filename;
    $ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w');
    $written =  "
        <?php 
     echo \$_SESSION['sub'].\"<br>\";
        ?>
    ";
    fwrite($ourFileHandle,$written);
    fclose($ourFileHandle);
    ?>
```

This is the newly written file m3.php

```
<?php 
         echo \$_SESSION['sub'].\"<br>\";
            ?>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You want to save session value into the file?

Comment: @daremachine yes exactly;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$written = "<?php echo '{$_SESSION['sub']} <br>'; ?>";
```

[Look at docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding